# Send redirect from a JAX-RS service

Tags: java, redirect, jax-rs

Is it possible to have a JAX-RS web service redirect to another web page?

Like as you would do with Servlet `response.sendRedirect("http://test/test.html")`.

The JAX-RS web service should itself redirect. I'm using RESTEasy if that's relevant.

Comment: The question is not clear, do you mean that the rest response should itself redirect, or that it should return a url that the caller can use as a destination url?

Comment: can you elaborate more on your question?? It's not clear...

Comment: @BenParsons - the REST web service should itself redirect.

Comment: Here's a complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13265693/712526

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Jersey or any JAX-RS implementation (including RestEasy) if your return type is a `Response` (or `HttpServletResponse`)
https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html

You can use either of the following:

```
Response.temporaryRedirect(URI)
```

---

```
Response.seeOther(URI)
```

"Temporary Redirect" returns a 307 status code while "See Other" returns 303.

Comment: Then it's done the same way because they both use javax.ws.rs.core.Response.

Comment: This link is broken

Comment: What if I want to return a permanent redirect (301) ? Should I use temporaryRedirect or seeOther or another method ?

Comment: And what about for 302?

Answer (score 5):

For those like me looking for 302 that fall on this answer.

By looking the code of

```
Response.temporaryRedirect(URI)
```

You can customize your response code like this :

```
Response.status(int).location(URI).build()
```

Note that status code are define in enum

```
Response.Status
```

And for example 302 is `Response.Status.FOUND`

Answer (score 2):

Extending smcg@ answer above,

You can achieve this by altering the request context in a `ContainerRequestFilter` by using `ContainerRequestContext.setRequestUri(URI)`. If you see the JAX-RS specification (Section 6.2) [**here**](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1589668574_af056072d473525f64c04ff25fd7831a), there is a mention of `@PreMatching` request filters. According to the documentation;

> A ContainerRequestFilter that is annotated with @PreMatching is executed upon
>   receiving a client request but before a resource method is matched. Thus, this type of filter has the ability
>   to modify the input to the matching algorithm (see Section 3.7.2) and, consequently, alter its outcome.

A very naive filter can be like this;

```
@PreMatching
class RedirectFilter: ContainerRequestFilter {
    override fun filter(requestContext: ContainerRequestContext?) {

      requestContext!!.setRequestUri(URI.create("<redirect_uri>"))
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted your reply. Please can you provide your example in Java rather than in Kotlin?