# How to redirect to html page with RESTEasy?

Tags: java, html, redirect, resteasy

I use RESTEasy 3.1.4-Final, and I have a method:

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response getInteractionsData(@Context UriInfo ui) {
        return Response.ok().entity("index.html").build();
    }
```

How to redirect to index.html? Now I get a plain text "index.html" (with response header text/html).
See also https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/ghrpv/

Before I used Servlet API for this target:

```
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        if (dispatcher != null) {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
```

But now i can't have *request* or *response*. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the answers to this post

[Redirect from JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435461/send-redirect-from-a-jax-rs-service)

```
Response.temporaryRedirect(URI)
```

OR

```
Response.seeOther(URI)
```

"Temporary Redirect" returns a 307 status code while "See Other" returns 303.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me where the index.html file should be located?

Comment: That's difficult for me to tell without looking at your precise setup but any exceptions you observe running the above code should give you a clue