# Redirect POST url on Payara 4.1 or 5 Server

Tags: http-post, redirect, http-redirect, payara

In Payara Server, version 4.1 or 5, is it possible to redirect a POST url?

I know that it is possible with a GET url (in Configuration > HTTP Service > Virtual Servers > server), but I want to do the same with a POST method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a JAX-RS class wich maps your POST URL and returns a `Response` with a re-direct (HTTP status 307). This is already answered here: [Send redirect from a JAX-RS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435461/send-redirect-from-a-jax-rs-service):

> You can use either of the following:

```
Response.temporaryRedirect(URI)
```

> or:

```
Response.seeOther(URI)
```

> "Temporary Redirect" returns a 307 status code while "See Other" returns 303.

This is independent of the Payara version and part of the JAX-RS specification.